# Adding a Macro to AfterUpdate Event on Linked Table using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, linked-tables

I'm wondering is there any way to add a macro to the AfterUpdate Table Event in VBA?

```
    Dim Db As Database, tDef As TableDef
    Set Db = CurrentDb
    Set tDef = Db.CreateTableDef("ARCH_CALL")      
    tDef.Connect = BuildLinkString(UserName)
    tDef.SourceTableName = CreateDataSourceString(BuildDataSourceString, "LinkedTableName")
    Db.TableDefs.Append tDef
```

I re-create the linked table after each login, so I need to re-associate the AfterUpdate Table Event as well.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to assign an event-driven Data Macro (Before Change, After Update, ...) to a *linked* table reference in Access. Stuff like that normally must be defined on the actual table itself: either an event-driven Data Macro on the "real" table in another Access database, or a trigger on the "real" table in SQL Server (or MySQL, or whatever). I'll be most interested if you do find a way to do what you describe.

Comment: Gord, Access 2013 let me create the event-driven Data Macro, but it doesn't seem to be working/triggering.

Comment: What method did you use to create the Data Macro? I just tried `Application.LoadFromText acTableDataMacro, ...` against an existing linked table and I found the same thing: it accepted the Data Macro definition but the macro doesn't seem to run.

Comment: I just used the Table Tools / Design Tab--> Create Data Macros --> AfterUpdate. I got to this toolbar by double clicking the table object in the Navigation bar.

Comment: Under Design View...

Comment: Interesting. In Access 2010 those options are all greyed out for linked tables in both Design View and Datasheet View. However, in Access 2013 they are enabled in Design View but still disabled in Datasheet View.

Comment: Thanks again, Gord.I will look for another way to trigger my Log() function which logs the changes in the datasheet in my subform control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoCmd.RunMacro "MacroName"
```

should do the trick.  Just tack it on at the end of the AfterUpdate event.

EDIT:

Why not just change the link instead of creating a new table?  Then you don't have to reassign a macro using VBA.

```
Set db = CurrentDB
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("ARCH_CALL")
tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=10.0.0.1;" _
  & "UID=testdb;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=abc;TABLE=dbo.ARCH_CALL"
tdf.RefreshLink
```

Comment: Thanks.  And how do I associate the AfterUpdate table event with a table using VBA? I don't know the syntax.

Comment: Try changing the link instead of recreating it.  See my edit above.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll give this a try.